# Why does operator[] only take one argument?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

There are plenty of questions related to operator[] only taking one argument, but I can't find one that actually says why.

For example, it seems a very natural extension of the language to have `matrix[0, 3]` call an `ElementT& operator[](SizeT x, SizeT y)` function.

Is there any particular reason (e.g. incompatibility) that this syntax isn't in the language, or anything besides lack of motivation actually preventing it from being added?

(Note: This has been marked a duplicate, but it is not. This question is "why isn't this syntax in the language?" not "how do I work around the issue?". As mentioned, there are plenty of questions that address the latter, but none that answer the former.)

Comment: Probably something to do with `a[1,3]` currently being perfectly valid syntax already (the `,` being the comma operator).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/tOJx2TcHpH0

Comment: Operator overloading in C++ can't really change the basics of how the overloaded operators work, and there is no operator `[]` in C++ which takes multiple values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Aside from short-circuiting and sequencing, which overloading `,`, `&&` and  `||` removes. Which can really throw people.

Comment: @FredOverflow This question is not a duplicate. I have explained why.

Comment: Then way you're asking now, it's off-topic. SO is not about discussing the designs of programming languages. Actually, it's not about discussing at all.

Comment: I asked a specific question about a specific design feature of a specific language, which has been provided with a definite answer. It wasn't simply a topic for discussion, and it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is the (little-used in this particular context) comma operator a wrench in the works which require a lengthy transition period to get this standardized, we already have another solution which people use:

```
ElementT& operator()(SizeT x, SizeT y)
```

Some matrix libraries in the wild use this form.  It's a little ugly, but welcome to C++.  :)

Comment: And others use (or also use) proxies, so you can just chain them.

Comment: Thanks, I had (blissfully) forgotten all about the comma operator.